# How to call function with the same name but from different trait inside ink-e2e-test

Tags: ink, smart-contract, testing, contracts, e2e

Let's say I have the following impl of my Contract:

```
impl Contract{
    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn my_fun(&self);
}

impl MyTrait1 for Contract {
    #[ink(message)]
    pub fn my_fun(&self);
}
```

how can I call my_fun::() inside ink-e2e test?

I'd like to use ink 5.0.0-rc and ink-e2e 5.0.0-rc.